# Form submission to google form using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I wrote the following code but then it's submitted Internal error appears. I have no ideas on what is going wrong.

```
<?php

//extract data from the post
//extract($_GET) ;
//set POST variables

//The form https://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?authkey=CJPbtZkI&hl=en&formkey=dEd5UFhRQ1ZfNzcwU1UwOVhIbF92cGc6MQ&ifq
$url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?authkey=CJPbtZkI&amp;hl=en&amp;formkey=dEd5UFhRQ1ZfNzcwU1UwOVhIbF92cGc6MQ&amp;ifq' ;
$fields = array(
'pageNumber'=>urlencode("0" ) ,
'backupCache'=>urlencode("") ,
'submit'=>urlencode("Submit"),
'entry.0.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.1.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.2.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.3.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.4.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.5.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.6.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.7.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.8.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.9.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.10.single'=>urlencode("") ,
'entry.11.single'=>urlencode(""),
'entry.12.single'=>urlencode("")
);
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&' ; }
rtrim($fields_string ,'&') ;
//open connection
$ch = curl_init() ; 
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml','Accept-Charset: UTF-8')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string) ;
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch) ;
print_r($fields_string);
//close connection
curl_close($ch) ;

?>
```

Comment: Hi, I am doing exactly the same thing and mine still doesnt work, would you please help if you can? where can i send you the code to?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious first problem is that the URL you are trying to use is HTML encoded (e.g. it has `&amp;` for `&`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add that :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Picky point, but your `$field_strings` variable still has the trailing ampersand. You'd need to do:

```
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string ,'&') ;
```